# Explanation of Sabbath please!

Tags: genesis, word-study, deuteronomy, moses, sabbath

In Genisis YHWH rests on the sabbath grammatically and historically; does the Hebrew term, "sabbath" refer to rest in general, by a deity, or does it refer to rest on a designated day, the deity had in mind and intends, no wiggle room, until time indefinite? Not being fluent in biblical languages, I seek understanding of the term, sabbath, and wonder if it is strictly a biblical word, and not found outside any use within the Tora or Tanakh, originally?

> Gen 2:2, 3 - And by the seventh day God had finished the work He had
> been doing; so on that day He **rested** from all His work. Then God
> blessed the seventh day and sanctified it, because on that day He
> **rested** from all the work of creation that He had accomplished.

Comment: Adjusting to rules sir! Thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 1):

First, the noun "Sabbath" is not mentioned in Gen 2:2, 3.  The closest we get is the verb שָׁבַת (sabath) which means, "*to cease, desist, rest*".

The first mention of the noun, שַׁבָּת "Sabbath", before the formal giving of the law at Sinai is in Ex 16:23, 25, 26, 29 in connection with observing the Sabbath by not collecting manna.

The formal giving of the Sabbath command is recorded in Ex 20:8-11 which is explicitly tied to the record in Gen 2:2, 3 by two mechanisms:

- the Sabbath command begins with "remember", ie, recall the origin and earlier practice
- The Sabbath command quotes two significant sections from Genesis creation account:

1. that God created the world in six days and rested on the seventh day
2. that God blessed the Sabbath day and sanctified/hallowed it (compare Gen 2:3)

The repetition of the command in Ex 31:17 repeats much of this information.

Lastly, while the noun "Sabbath" and the verb "sabath" are quintessentially Hebrew, the same words have been borrowed by other languages, both ancient and modern such as:

- Chaldee Syriac, sapta = "Sabbath"
- Samarian, shab-bath = "Sabbath"
- Babylonian sabatu = "Sabbath"
- Assyrian sabati = "Sabbath"
- Arabic (very ancient), shiyar = "chief of rejoicing day"
- Arabic (old and modern), sasabt = "Sabbath
- Ge'ez Ethiopian in Abyssinia, sanbat = "Sabbath"
- Coptic, pi sabbaton = "The Sabbath"
- Urdu & Hindistani, shamba = "Sabbath"
- Latin, Sabbatum = "Sabbath"
- etc, etc

There are many more.

Comment: Without presenting evidence, making the claim that these other languages borrowed from Hebrew is tenuous at best.

Comment: @Traildude - do you not see the etymology?  The words are the same form and the meaning is the same.

Comment: Yes, the forms are the same.  But without presenting evidence, making the claim that Hebrew is original and the others derivative is tenuous at best.

Comment: @Traildude - I thought it was obvious since "sabbath" is a Hebrew word and is not in any of these other languages except as the name of a day.

Comment: Unless you have dates showing how early your examples were used compared to the Hebrew use there's no way to tell which was first.  Some of your examples are certainly derivative of the Hebrew, e.g. Latin, but others are not.  And in fact the word appears in Sumerian/Akkadian which probably preceded Hebrew.  But the Babylonian and Assyrian use may also predate the Hebrew use.  There are a fair number of words from ancient Hebrew that are shared across the ancient near east and determining which is original -- if any! -- is difficult.

Comment: @Traildude - I think you have missed the point.  The fact is that such an idea was very common across many languages, regardless of which was first.  This demonstrates that the idea of sabbath keeping was very ancient and widespread.

Comment: I didn't miss the point at all:  the answer asserts that the word was borrowed from Hebrew by these other languages, which requires that the Hebrew use be the first.  How widespread "the idea of sabbath keeping" may have been is not relevant to that.  In fact for that matter, the inclusion of the list of examples from other languages is of far less value than it would have if dates for those examples were provided; with dates, the Hebrew use would be put in its historical context, showing where it may have originated along with where it is derivative of the Hebrew.

Comment: @Traildude - but "sabbath" is a Hebrew word.  It did not come from these other languages, yet it ends up in these languages.

Comment: You're engaging in circular reasoning, saying that the Hebrew is first because it is first.  There is strong evidence that the Akkadian sebūtu and šabattu as well as Ugaritic.  The Aramaic and Arabic are plainly derivative, as is the Greek, and the Latin via Greek, but merely claiming that Akkadian and Ugaritic versions are derivative fails in the face of evidence.

Comment: @Traildude - let us assume you are correct - it does not alter the fact that all these people observed the sabbath.

Answer (score 1):

The weekly sabbath day in the Bible, and to the Hebrews, is always and forever the seventh day of the week, observed from sundown Friday to sundown Saturday.  God rested from all His work on that day, He blessed that day and hallowed it, and commanded it (Gen. 2:2, Ex. 20:8-11, 31:13-17). There were also other sabbaths given to them in addition to the weekly sabbath, which fall on different days of the week (Lev. 23:24).  In the English dictionary the Sabbath can mean the seventh day, Sunday, or a time of rest, depending on the audience.